# Sign of failure of potentiometer

Tags: potentiometer, repair

Is it a sign of failure of a potentiometer when it doesn't have a fixed ohm value (the MM reading keeps changing) at any turn position, and what must be done to fix this particular symptom?

Comment: Potentiometer and varistor are different things. Please clarify. Did you measure inside a circuit or the component alone? Show us! If it is a potentiometer measured directly with no other components interfering it is likely burnt out and needs replacement.

Comment: I would agree that using contact spray to clean the contacts as some have mentioned should be the first thing to try as it is the simplest. Otherwise if it doesn't improve anything then it's most likely a faulty pot (and/or dry solder joint) and will need replacement or soldering at the board level ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to use a variable resistor, depending on whether we expect the wiper to carry any significant current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fma0KV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The normal way to use a Potentiometer is with zero current flowing through the wiper, as shown in the first diagram. It's used to drive a high impedance load, selecting a part of the input voltage for output. As such, a small and variable resistance between track and wiper does not matter too much, to first order anyway.

Where you want a two-terminal variable resistor, it's normally called a Rheostat. They will often be wirewound, so you get a good reliable connection between track and wiper, and a connection that's robust to local heating.

If you are forced to use a potentiometer as a rheostat, it's usual practice to connect one end of the track to the wiper, so that when (not if) the wiper jumps off the track during movement, the resistance only increases to the track resistance, rather than becoming open circuit.

Potentiometers tend to have a lightweight track, that can easily be damaged. If there's current flowing through the track/wiper junction while the potentiometer is moved, there's a danger that the wiper jumping off the track could cause arcs and rapid damage to the track.

If you need to use it as a rheostat, then any resistance fluctuation with movement will be bad. Replace it. If you are using it in potentiometer mode, it may still work OK in your application. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

The sign of a bad potentiometer is a jumping of the resistance as the wiper is stroked across the range of the potentiometer.  You can sometimes see this by using your multimeter on the resistance scale (ohms).

The better technique is to remove the pot from the circuit.  Place a DC voltage across the potentiometer.  Connect an oscilloscope from the negative lead to the center lead or the wiper.  By slowly turning the potentiometer you should see a smooth trace on the oscilloscope as you turn the pot.  If the pot has issues you will most likely see the trace jump as you turn the pot.

Good Pot:
[image: Good Pot]

Bad Pot:
[image: Bad Pot]

In my experience the fix for a bad potentiometer is to replace it.  You can try cleaning the wiper surface, if you can get access to it.  For vintage old 1970's and 1980's equipment, which used potentiometers for calibration adjustments - it would sometimes be helpful to repeatedly turn the pot across the range to get onto a new area where the wiper was not resting on a dead spot (high resistance).

Comment: Note that many potentiometers don't let you rotate them a full 360° like yours appears to. Just in case someone wonders why their potentiometer can only make a triangle wave, not a sawtooth wave.

Comment: It's pretty easy to fix a dirty pot by just spraying some contact cleaner into it and turning it back and forth a few times, too. No need to get physical access to the track. Of course replacing it is an option, but I'd say try cleaning it first.

Answer (score 1):

The usual sign of pot' degradation (not outright failure) I've seen is for a DMM resistance reading to be flickery in some pot' positions and very steady in others.

That is a usually a sign of dirt on the resistive track. A simple method of fixing it that doesn't involve taking a pot' apart is:

- Spray switch cleaner (e.g. Servisol) with its straw into the pot's insides.
- Turn the pot's knob back and forward to the limits a lot, say 10 times.
- Repeat that a few times.

After that, they're much better, often good as new.

Goodness knows how many hi-fi volume/tone controls I fixed doing that in the 80s/90s but I left a lot of people happy with their rejuvenated stereos and they worked fine for many many years afterwards. In was a common home fix done by lots of engineers I knew.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use an oscilloscope (with АC input) instead of a multimeter to see the breaks.

Try to "fix" the pot by spraying it (without opening) with contact spray or simply with deodorant.

An older technique is to open the pot and rub it with a graphite pencil:-)

It is possible that there is a poor contact in the end terminals of the potentiometer. Wiggle them to check and squeeze them with pliers.

Finally, if possible, swap the pot end terminals.